# How can I get this GridView to appear in the center of my Window?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm stuck right now on this QML Item. It's a simple 2x3 grid which seems to be sticking to the left of the screen. If I apply `anchors.centerIn: parent`, it centers the GridView but ignores my TopMargin property. If I could get any assistance on this it'd be greatly appreciated. I know I can apply a leftMargin: to it but it's sort of ugly.

```
GridView {

    id: gridView
    interactive: false
    clip: true

    // anchors.centerIn: parent
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: titleBarContainer.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: 20
    anchors.right: parent.right

    width: 400
    height: parent.height

    currentIndex: -1

    cellWidth: 200
    cellHeight: 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...

anchors.top: titleBarContainer.bottom
anchors.topMargin: 20
anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

width: 400
height: parent.height

...
```

Comment: Looks like that did it.. guess I was stupid. Thank you!

Comment: Although I should note.. it continues to stick to the left if I use parent.width instead of `400` for the width value.. do you know why?

Comment: That would make the GridView cover the entire width of the parent, which makes horizontal center anchoring meaningless. What happens inside the GridView is that it lays out its items starting from the top left corner.